# xsl:Template match xml node

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am new to [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) and have a very basic question, the following are xsl and xml files.
I expect "xxx" to be outputted for every xml node "inhouse" (template match). 
But I am not getting it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">         
  <xsl:template match="CustomerData">    
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>        
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="1.5cm" margin-top="0cm">
          <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="0cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="0cm"/>     
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>  
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">                                 
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">  
            <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8.5pt" font-weight="normal">       
                abc                             
            </fo:block>         
             <xsl:template match="inhouse">  
                <fo:block color="#053679">
                      xxx            
              </fo:block>                 
           </xsl:template>
        </fo:flow>      
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CustomerData>
    <inhouse>   
    <customerList>
        <customer>           
            <name>Tom</name>
        </customer>
    </customerList>  
  </inhouse>
</CustomerData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have a template match for **inhouse** within your template match for **CustomerData**

```
<xsl:template match="CustomerData">  
   ...
   <xsl:template match="inhouse">  
       ....
   </xsl:template>
   ....
</xsl:template>
```

You are not allowed to nest templates in this way. What you need to do is move your **inhouse** template out of the current template, but instead tell the XSLT processor to start looking for other templates at that point with **xsl:apply-templates**. Something like this structure

```
<xsl:template match="CustomerData">  
   ...
   <xsl:apply-templates select="inhouse" />
   ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inhouse">  
       ....
</xsl:template>
```

In fact, it could be slightly better to replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="inhouse" />` with just `<xsl:apply-templates />` as this would handle the case where you have other elements other than **inhouse** you wanted to match.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">         
  <xsl:template match="CustomerData">    
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>        
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="1.5cm" margin-top="0cm">
          <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="0cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="0cm"/>     
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>  
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">                                 
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">  
            <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="8.5pt" font-weight="normal">       
                abc                             
            </fo:block>         
             <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:flow>      
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="inhouse">  
       <fo:block color="#053679">
         xxx            
        </fo:block>                 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: small folo wup question when I use <xsl:apply-templates />  it will search a template (if exists) for every node ?

Comment: It will search for templates that match the child nodes of the node you are currently positioned on (In this case, any child of the **CustomerData** element). However, if it does not find any explicit matching templates, then XSLT's "built-in templates" will be used which will recursively search all descendent nodes.